# iOS - NSOperationQueue not firing in order

Tags: ios, asynchronous, synchronization, nsoperationqueue

I am trying to queue up multiple asynchronous requests to load data into some objects. I need them to be executed in order and wait for each object's `loadDataWithCompletion` to be fired before the next one starts.

When all data is loaded for each object, the object is then checked to see if the data is valid.
If the object is marked as valid, it is added to a temporary array, then the next object should execute it's `loadData` method and repeat this process.

Since each object's `loadData` method is asynchronous and the `completionBlock` may not be called for a few seconds, I need to ensure the final `operationBlock` for copying the temporary array into the final one isn't fired until all objects finished their `loadDataWithCompletion` and `isValid` check.

However, right now the final `completionOperation` block is fired before any of the `completionBlock` in each object's `loadDataWithCompletion` method is fired. (Verified with debugger and breakpoints)

Any advice on how to ensure all my asynchronous data loads are fired and finished before the `completionOperation` is fired?

**Here is my current code:**

```
- (void)loadCustomObjectsWithCompletion:(void (^)())completionBlock
        if (self.operationQueue) {
            [self.operationQueue cancelAllOperations];
        }

        NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
        operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
        self.operationQueue = operationQueue;
        NSOperation *previousOperation;

        NSMutableArray *validObjects = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        for (CustomObject *customObject in self.myCustomObjects) {
            NSOperation *operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
                    [customObject loadDataWithCompletion:^{
                        if (customObject.isValid) {
                            [validObjects addObject:customObject];
                        }
                }];
            }];
            if (previousOperation) {
                [operation addDependency:previousOperation];
            }
            [operationQueue addOperation:operation];
            previousOperation = operation;
        }

        NSOperation *completionOperation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
            self.validObjects = validObjects;

            if (completionBlock) {
                completionBlock();
            }
        }];

        if (previousOperation) {
            [completionOperation addDependency:previousOperation];
        }
        [operationQueue addOperation:completionOperation];
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a `dispatch_group` with the stuff you want to do after all the load calls are finished in the `dispatch_notify` block.

Comment: Ahhh @dan that did the trick! Thank you! Would you mind re-posting your comment as an answer so I can accept and give you the credit? Thanks!